# Write C++ statement(s) to do the following:

Tags: c++

e. Use for loop to output the value of an element of array A if its index / subscript is a multiple of 2 or 3

The following is the code I have done, but I can't get the last part (letter e) right. Can someone please help?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A[50] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49 };

    int first;
    first = A[0];
    cout << "First element: " << first << endl;
    A[24] = 26; 
    A[9] = (3 * 39) + 10;  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
            cout << A << " ";
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to check if it's a multiple of 2 or 3, but you use the numbers 3 and 5 in the code.

Comment: Your d is wrong.  You're using `39`, not `A[39]` (which is the 40th element).

Comment: nobody told you to initialize the array

Comment: @mkrieger1 How could this question be more focused? It is better focused than many. It is asking for debugging help which is frowned upon, sure, but does that warrant a close?

Comment: I think that code won't even compile... And I think the error message tells you exactly what is the problem. If you don't underatand the error, you should ask about the error.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful comments! Ya'll are blessings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A[9] = (3 * 39) + 10;
```

should be

```
A[9] = (3 * A[39]) + 10;
```

and

```
if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
        cout << A << " ";
```

should be

```
if (i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0)
        cout << A[i] << " ";
```

Comment: Thank you, I've edited those parts but I still have an error in this line:
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

I know I'm something >:-(((

Comment: @Tricia that loop seems perfectly fine. What is it that goes wrong? It would also help if you would provide details about your problems: Does it not compile? (What's the error message?) Does it compile but crashes? Does it compile and run but produces the wrong output? What do you expect, and what do you get instead?

Comment: @Tricia The problem is that you haven't declared `n`. I guess you really should have this `for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)`

Comment: @Peter The program runs fine but the only output that I get is the "first element of the array" when I am supposed to get another output that is: "the value of an element of array A if its index / subscript is a multiple of 2 or 3"

Comment: @Peter omg!! that's the problem. It was the n :----(( Thank you so much. I got it! Sorry for asking for this kind of help. Anyway, thanks a mil!

Comment: @Tricia Write that (more precise -- I suppose you don't want the literal output "the value of an element of array A if its index / subscript is a multiple of 2 or 3", because you never write that. in the program. (Instead you want  output in the form "0 3 6 9 ...".) Also, John is right: The program s it is in the answer will not compile: You cannot `cout << A` and you did not declare `n`.

Comment: So how could the program run if you never defined `n`? It should not even compile, as @john said.